# center the map on user's location didn't show the blue dot

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a tab bar, one is used to display the map. When I switch to this tab bar, it will request permission and get the current location automatically.

I finished the code, set the simulated location to Apple, it will show a blue dot in the center of the screen, but when I chose the custom location, specify a location, the blue dot is not displayed in the center of the map.

I need to drag the map, and will find the blue dot near the center location about 1~2km. I tested on the real device and have the same problem.

use the method to show the current location auto, but not show the blue dot.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
            locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        }else{
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        
    }
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation = locations.last!
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 100, 100)
        mapView.setRegion(mapView.regionThatFits(coordinateRegion), animated: true)
        location = newLocation
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager = nil
}
```

I added a button - when it not show the blue dot, clicking the button will set the blue dot in the center of the map. The two methods have the same function, but they produce different views. Why?

```
@IBAction func showUser() {
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 100, 100)
        mapView.setRegion(mapView.regionThatFits(region), animated: true)
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you set `showsUserLocation` to true?  Also, why not just use `userTrackingMode = .follow` ?

Comment: i have checked the user location in map view's attributes inspector.where to use the userTrackingMode？

Comment: You can just set it as a property of your map view in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: no...it doesn't work.the point is why i use the Apple coordinate it show correct,use the custom location it will have the problem

Comment: @Magicle see my answer

Comment: @Magicle Try my new answer, I actually build a demo and it's working properly with updating location, and centers the mapview with blue dot

Comment: @Magicle Did you try or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use this coding to update to location with center of mapview

Please add this keys into info.plist file

```
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>


override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        map.delegate = self
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        }else{
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        mapView .setCenter(userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
    }
```

You can download demo from [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2jcprx1dwtvjpu/DEMO%20SWIFT%203.0.zip?dl=0)

Comment: thx,i will have a try.could you test my code ,whether it have the same problem:)

Comment: yeah sure, please share the link of demo

Comment: did you add this keys into info.plist file ? @Magicle and also you have to enabled showUserLocation as         "YOUR_MAPVIEW_OUTLET".showsUserLocation = true

Comment: yes.if i choose the location to Apple,it shows correct,but if i choose custom location ,the dot is deviate the center

Comment: So please accept my answer and upvote the same. @Magicle please

Comment: @Magicle If not solve then please share your demo with me, I will try to solve it and if it solved your problem then please accept my answer and upvote same

Comment: it's working with you code,but how to specified a region,like the function of MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 1000, 1000)